# permission denied error when I run make install to get setup with doxygen

Tags: linux, doxygen

I am following the [steps](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html#gitrepos) from the doxygen online documentation to get doxygen up and running on OS X 10.7.5. I successfully cloned the repo, ran `./configure` and `make` and then skipped the part that said `make distclean`. When I try to run `make install`  I get the following error:

```
akh2103: make install
/usr/bin/install -d //usr/local/bin
install: chmod 755 //usr/local/bin: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxygen        //usr/local/bin
install: //usr/local/bin/doxygen: Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 71
```

1. I am new to linux/open source development (from .NET) and I'm assuming that making (creating the binary) is different from installing the built code. So I am assuming that I need to run `make install` even if I am not running the `make distclean` commands
2. Assuming I need to run `make install` how do I go about debugging/getting around this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo make install` if you want to install something in /usr/local/bin, or use the `--prefix` option of configure to install to a writable location.